# Function on convex set is convex if all rays are convex

Tags: convex-analysis

Consider the function $f:D\rightarrow\mathbb{R}$ for $D\subset\mathbb{R}^n$ an open convex set.  Furthermore, suppose that $g(t)=f(t\boldsymbol{x})$ is convex for all $\boldsymbol{x}\in D$.  Is it true that $f$ is convex?  Or is there a counter example?

I haven't been able to find a counter example.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The statement is trivially true for $n=1$, but false for all $n \ge 2$. As a counter-example, define
$$
   f: \mathbb R^n \to \mathbb R, \, f(x_1, x_2, \ldots, x_n) = | x_1\, x_2 |
$$
For fixed $\boldsymbol{x} = (x_1, x_2, \ldots, x_n)$,
$$
   g: \mathbb R \to \mathbb R, \,g(t) = f(t \boldsymbol{x}) = t^2 | x_1\, x_2 |
$$
is convex, but $f$ is not convex because
$$
   \frac 14 = f(\frac 12, \frac 12, 0, \ldots) \nleq 
 \frac 12 f(1, 0, 0, \ldots) + \frac 12 f(0, 1, 0, \ldots) = 0 \quad.
$$

Answer (score 0):

It can be easily proved that a function $f$ is convex if and only if $t \mapsto f(x_0+th)$ is convex (in $t$) for any $x_0$ and $h$. This is stated [here](http://ece.tamu.edu/~cui/ECEN629/lecture2.pdf), and follows from the definitions. 
I don't believe that you can conclude, if you ignore translations, i.e. $x_0$.

Comment: I know you can't for a general domain $D$, but if we assume that $D$ is open and convex I was wondering if you could.

Comment: Convexity is equivalent to convexity of the restriction to any line segment contained in $D$. You are considering only line segments that begin at the origin. I am skeptical...

Comment: skeptical that it's true?